# Marcar/desmarcar todas as checkboxes criadas dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Estou a criar checkboxes a partir da BD. Tenho uma outra que define se todas as outras ficam marcadas ou não. Quando corro a primeira vez funciona bem, mas à segunda já não.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row smart-form">
  <section class="col col-3">
   <div class="checkbox">
     <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="selectAll" id="check0" class="checkbox style-0 checkDoc">
      <span>Marcar/Desmarcar todos</span>
     </label>
   </div>
  </section>
 </div>
<div class="row smart-form">
 @for(dt <- docTipo) {
  <section class="col col-3">
    <div class="checkbox">
     <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="docTipo" id="check@dt.id" class="checkbox style-0">
      <span>@dt.descricao</span>
     </label>
    </div>
  </section>
 }
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).on('change','.checkDoc', function() {
            if(this.checked) {
                $("input[name=docTipo]").attr("checked", true);
                $("input[name=docTipo]").attr("disabled", true);
            } else {
                $("input[name=docTipo]").attr("checked", false);
                $("input[name=docTipo]").attr("disabled", false);
            }
        });
```

Ao primeiro click na checkbox de controlo todas as outras ficam selecionadas e disabled, ao segundo click fica tudo descelecionado e enabled, ao terceiro só ficam disabled mas não ficam marcadas. Já inspecionei elemento, e é adicionado o checked em cada uma mas no browser não aparece o visto :s

**Inspecionar Elemento**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Podes colocar o HTML renderizado? e se possivel juntar um jsFiddle?

Comment: Nunca fiz jsFiddle :s E as checkboxes estão a ser criadas a partir da BD, penso que o problema de não funcionar possa vir daí.

Comment: Ok, não tem problema. Junta então o HTML que aparece no lado do cliente/browser.

Comment: Penso que seja isso que queira ver, desculpe mas sou novo a trabalhar nisto :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deves usar o [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) e não o [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). Na documentação do `.attr()` encontra-se a explicação:

> To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the *checked*, *selected*, or *disabled* state of form elements, use the `.prop()` method.

Em portuguûes:

> Para propriedades do DOM como *checked*, *selected*, ou estado *disabled* de elementos form ou checkboxes use `.prop()`

Entretanto essas linhas todas dentro do event handler podiam ser reduzidas a:

```
$(document).on('change', '.checkDoc', function () {
    $("input[name=docTipo]").prop({
        checked: this.checked,
        disabled: this.checked
    });
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7mqx59f0/

Comment: Era exatamente isso que precisava, obrigado ;)

Answer (score 3):

Utilize o `on click` e `prop` ao inves de `attr`

```
$(document).on( "click",'input[type=checkbox][name=selectAll]', function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('input[type=checkbox][name=docTipo]').prop('checked',isChecked);
});
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria, está perfeitamente funcional ;) Obrigado